# Error while setting Onvif Camera time

Tags: c#, datetime, onvif

I am setting onvif camera time using odm dll but when i am calling SetSystemDateandTime it is giving me "400 bad request from server" error and i think this error arises due to **wrong posix conversion of timezone.**

> Here is my code:

I am passing setdatetimetype = ntp,daylisghtsaving = false, timezone in posix format, datetime = null.

```
public void SetOnvifCameraTime(string setdatetimeType, bool daylightSaving, System.TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo, System.DateTime systemDateTime)
{
    var rule = GetSystemTimeZoneRule(System.DateTime.Now, timeZoneInfo);
    var std_offset = -timeZoneInfo.BaseUtcOffset.TotalSeconds.ToInt32();
    PosixTz.Dst dst = null;

    if( rule!= null)
    {  
 // setting dst  if available
        var start = PosixTzExtensions.GetPosixRuleFromTransitionTime(rule.DaylightTransitionStart);
        var end = PosixTzExtensions.GetPosixRuleFromTransitionTime(rule.DaylightTransitionEnd);
        var dst_offset = std_offset - rule.DaylightDelta.TotalSeconds.ToInt32();
        dst = new PosixTz.Dst("DaylisghtTime", dst_offset, start, end);                

    }

    var posixTz = new   PosixTz(PosixTzWriter.NormalizeName(timeZoneInfo.StandardName), std_offset, dst);
    onvif.services.TimeZone timezone = new onvif.services.TimeZone();
    timezone.tz = posixTz.Format();   // time zone in posix format
    SetDateTimeType setdatetimeenumtype = SetDateTimeType.ntp;;

    var setTime = session.SetSystemDateAndTime(setdatetimeenumtype, daylightSaving, timezone, null).RunSynchronously();
}
```

So, I checked into the Onvif device manager and tried to set the camera time but it is giving me the error "invalid time zone".

I also checked the packets in wireshark and figure out the same problem "Invalid time zone format".

So i am confused now, whether this error is due to my code or odm dll?

And if there is any API or class available for the conversion of timezone to posix format string?

**Edit:**

I have discovered that i was sending correct timezone in posix format but the camera manufacturer hasn't implemented it correctly, that is why it is giving me  "Invalid Timezone " error in my code as well as in Onvif Device Manager.

> Camera Info:

Make :- Sony

Model :- SNC-CH110

Does anyone know, how the manufacturer has implemented the time setting in device?

Or any idea how can i still implement time setting in the camera?

Comment: If you still got problem, could you provide xml (from wireshark) you are sending to device, and one Onvif manager is sending? I checked in my pc and it works.

Comment: Or maybe your camera does not support this?

Comment: yes, camera support this feature @kajojeq

Comment: Try to find camera SDK documentation and find there how you can change it via http POST. You can also try to read it from wireshark when you change datetime via internet browser

Comment: @kajojeq,  calls for setting time from the internet browser to the camera is not onvif call so timezone is not in the posix format.

Comment: Yes I know, it was answer for: 'Or any idea how can i still implement time setting in the camera?'. Try on Sony forum. When I can't implement something for particular device by Onvif I use http post method from SDK.

Comment: @NaveenVerma I faced the same problem with different cameras. I wrote an answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26630249/convert-a-posix-style-timezone-to-timezoneinfo-in-c-sharp-net/40286544#40286544) about conversion of POSIX to TimeZoneInfo. It works for the cameras that Im working with. Let me know whether it works for you or not.

Comment: @aminexplo thanks for your comment,Your answer works fine for me.But i have already implemented the posix to timezoneinfo conversion. In my case it was the problem on the camera side(they were the old cameras). They haven't implemented the onvif protocol correctly.

Comment: @NaveenVerma Yes it is common. I have seen lots of ONVIF implementation error in different cameras. The newer the camera is, the less implementation errors you face.