# Convert .Net TimeZoneInfo to POSIX time zone

Tags: c#, .net, timezone, posix

I need to convert a timezone in .Net to a [POSIX timezone](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aix-posix/). I can get daylights saving start, end, and delta from `TimeZoneInfo` via `GetAdjustmentRules`, but then I would still be missing the timezone abbreviation codes (e.g. MST/MDT, PST/PDT, etc). Doing this in C# .Net.

Essentially, what I'm looking for is the opposite of this: [Convert a posix style timezone to timezoneinfo in c# .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26630249/convert-a-posix-style-timezone-to-timezoneinfo-in-c-sharp-net)

Is there an existing solution for something like this? Or does anyone know where I could obtain the standard and daylight time abbreviation codes?

EDIT: I just got a message that this question was closed because someone misunderstood it as seeking recommendations rather than a solution to a problem. I don't know how whoever closed it came to that conclusion, but no recommendations were queried.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? That format is rarely used apart from AIX and has quite a few problems - what happens if the rules change, like they do every couple of years in Russia? The IANA/Olson time zones (what that link refers to as Olson) are the defacto standard for all systems, from smartphones to airline mainframes. In .NET you can use NodaTime to work with IANA timezones. If you need to communicate with AIX you should probably use Olson

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Working with a series of devices that have seemingly purged the standard timezone libraries from its Linux distros, instead opting for the POSIX standard. I'll give NodaTime a try. Thanks!

Comment: I shudder to think what will happens when the rules change. In any case, you could use NodaTime which comes with a compiled tzdata database, but I suspect you want to be able to parse the TZ environment variable. In any case you *shouldn't* depend on TimeZoneInfo. Time to ping the NodaTime authors I think

Comment: Looks there was a [NodaTime Issue](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/issues/1140) about TimeZoneInfo failures on Linux and how they fixed it for the library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just added support for POSIX time zone strings as an add-on for my [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) project.  It is in a separate package called [`TimeZoneConverter.Posix`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TimeZoneConverter.Posix/).  Install that, and you can do the following:

```
string posix = PosixTimeZone.FromTimeZoneInfo(SomeTimeZoneInfoObject);
```

Also, you can simply provide either a Windows time zone ID or an IANA time zone name, and that will work also:

```
string posix = PosixTimeZone.FromWindowsTimeZoneId("Eastern Standard Time");
// Result: "EST5EDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0"

string posix = PosixTimeZone.FromIanaTimeZoneName("Australia/Sydney");
// Result: "AEST-10AEDT,M10.1.0,M4.1.0/3"
```

Keep in mind that you are still subject to the limitations of POSIX time zones:

- They can only support two transitions per year.
- Not all time zone transitions are for DST.  Some are for changes in standard time, and that isn't reflected here.  They will look like DST transitions.
- They don't provide any historical changes unto themselves.

On the last point, the samples shown above use the *current* year, but there are also overloads to supply a year to generate a string specific to that year.

Answer (score 0):

I am late to this party, but I found this post while looking to see if Microsoft had implemented anything yet. It would be nice of the .NET TimeZoneInfo class had a method for this.
Some years ago I wrote something to convert a .NET TimeZoneInfo object to a posix time zone string. It's not perfect - it's not easy to get the time zone name abbreviation, and posix does not support complex time zones.

```
// Class for creating and validating Posix Time Zone strings
// https://muman.ch, 2014.03.20
// All rights reversed

using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;

namespace MattLabs
{
    public static class PosixTimeZone
    {
        // Default transition time is 2am, 02:00:00
        private static DateTime DefaultTransitionTime = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0);

        // 0h00, use this for midnight, since 24h00 is and invalid time
        private static DateTime ZeroHour = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);

        // 24h00, this is 0h00 of the next day, it may be used by IANA rules 
        private static TimeSpan Hours24 = new TimeSpan(0, 24, 0, 0, 0);


        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the posix time zone string for a .NET TimeZoneInfo object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="tzi"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string GetPosixTZString(TimeZoneInfo tzi)
        {
            try {
                if (!tzi.SupportsDaylightSavingTime) {
                    // always standard time
                    return "UTC" + GetTZOffsetString(tzi.BaseUtcOffset);
                }

                // get standard time and daylight saving time abbreviations
                string std = GetTZAbbreviation(tzi, false);
                string dst = GetTZAbbreviation(tzi, true);

                // find the current transition rule which is active for this year
                // note! posix strings cannot define more than two transitions
                TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule[] rules = tzi.GetAdjustmentRules();
                if (rules == null) {
                    // must have rules if it has daylight saving time!
                    Debug.Assert(false, "Missing rules");
                    return std + GetTZOffsetString(tzi.BaseUtcOffset);
                }
                TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule currentRule = null;
                DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

                foreach (TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule rule in rules) {
                    if (rule.DateEnd < now) {
                        // historical rule
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (rule.DateEnd >= now) {
                        // current rule
                        currentRule = rule;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (currentRule == null) {
                    // no active rule, assume always standard time
                    return std + GetTZOffsetString(tzi.BaseUtcOffset);
                }

                // get UTC offsets
                string dstOffset = string.Empty;
                // the default DST offset is one hour ahead of standard time, don't show if one hour ahead
                if (currentRule.DaylightDelta != new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0)) {
                    dstOffset = GetTZOffsetString(tzi.BaseUtcOffset + currentRule.DaylightDelta);
                }
                string stdOffset = GetTZOffsetString(tzi.BaseUtcOffset);

                // get posix transition rules
                string dstRule = GetTZRuleString(currentRule.DaylightTransitionStart);
                string stdRule = GetTZRuleString(currentRule.DaylightTransitionEnd);

                string tzString = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3},{4},{5}", std, stdOffset, dst, dstOffset, dstRule, stdRule);

                // runtime validation
                if (!IsValidPosixTZString(tzString)) {
                    Debug.Assert(false);
                }
                return tzString;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Debug.Assert(false, ex.Message);
            }
            return null;
        }

        private static string GetTZRuleString(TimeZoneInfo.TransitionTime tt)
        {
            string rule = string.Empty;

            // changeover at midnight is actually 0:00 of the next day from the posix TZ point of view
            DateTime time = tt.TimeOfDay;
            bool midnight = time.Hour == 23 && time.Minute == 59 && time.Second == 59;
            if (midnight) {
                time = ZeroHour;            // 0h00
            }
            if (tt.IsFixedDateRule) {
                //TODO does this work for 31/12 at 24h?
                int day = tt.Day;
                int month = tt.Month;
                int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
                if (midnight) {
                    if (++day > GetDaysInMonth(year, month)) {
                        day = 1;
                        if (++month > 12) {
                            Debug.Assert(false);    // should never happen
                        }
                    }
                }
                DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, day);
                rule = (date.DayOfYear - 1).ToString();
                //TODO "Jxxx" for ignore leap year? when to use it? or not?
            }
            else {
                int day = (int)tt.DayOfWeek;
                int week = tt.Week;
                if (midnight) {
                    if (++day > 6) {
                        day = 0;
                    }
                }
                rule = string.Format("M{0}.{1}.{2}", tt.Month, week, day);
            }

            // omit the time if it it the posix default 02:00:00
            if (time == DefaultTransitionTime) {
                return rule;
            }

            // append the time
            return string.Format("{0}/{1}", rule, GetTODString(time));
        }

        private static string GetTZOffsetString(TimeSpan timeSpan)
        {
            // 'offset' is "±hh:[mm[:ss]]", 'hh' may be a single digit, 0≤hh≤24
            string offset = timeSpan.ToString(@"h\:mm\:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Replace(":00", string.Empty);
            if (timeSpan <= TimeSpan.Zero) {
                // no need to show the + sign
                //offset = '+' + offset;
            }
            else {
                offset = '-' + offset;
            }
            return offset;
        }

        private static string GetTODString(DateTime time)
        {
            // midnight is 24h00, not 23:59:59
            // note: this currently never happens because we set it to 'ZeroHour' before this is called
            if (time.Hour == 23 && time.Minute == 59 && time.Second == 59) {
                return "24";
            }

            // time-of-day string, "hh:[mm[:ss]]", 'hh' may be a single digit, 0≤hh≤24
            return time.ToString(@"H\:mm\:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Replace(":00", string.Empty);
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Get the time zone name abbreviation from the TimeZoneInfo names
        /// e.g. PST = Pacific Standard Time
        /// A better way to do this is with a manually created look-up table, 
        /// because the MS TimeZonInfo does not contain enough information.
        /// But this hack works quite well, it just takes the capital letters
        /// of each word in the name. This is probably OK because the abbreviations 
        /// are only used for display.
        /// 
        /// TODO If this is not good enough, add a conversion table created from
        /// from this information, or the IANA database. The table should be updated 
        /// whenever the IANA database changes.
        ///     https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="tzi"></param>
        /// <param name="daylightName"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static string GetTZAbbreviation(TimeZoneInfo tzi, bool daylightName)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            string name = daylightName ? tzi.DaylightName : tzi.StandardName;

            // a few special cases for common time zones
            if (name.StartsWith("US Eastern")) {
                name = name.Substring(3);
            }
            switch (name) {
                case "GMT Standard Time":
                    return "GMT";
                case "GMT Daylight Time":
                    return "BST";
                case "W. Europe Standard Time":
                case "Central Europe Standard Time":        // (microsoft error)
                case "Central European Standard Time":
                case "Romance Standard Time":               // who chose "Romance"? too much Absinthe?
                    return "CET";
                case "W. Europe Daylight Time":
                case "Central Europe Daylight Time":
                case "Central European Daylight Time":
                case "Romance Daylight Time":
                    return "CEST";                          // Central European Summer Time
                default:
                    break;
            }

            char[] terminators = new char[] { '[', '(' };
            string[] words = name.Split(' ');

            foreach (string word in words) {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(word)) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (word.IndexOfAny(terminators) >= 0) {
                    break;
                }
                char ch = word[0];
                if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') {
                    sb.Append(ch);
                }
            }
            while (sb.Length < 3) {
                sb.Append('T');
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Validates a posix time zone string.
        /// See https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html
        /// and https://data.iana.org/time-zones/theory.html
        // 
        // stdzone [ dstzone [, rule [, rule] ] ]
        //
        // stdzone  :=  name offset
        // dstzone  :=  name [offset]
        // name     :=  3 or more characters, any except ":,+-0123456789<>"
        //          |=  <[+|-]nn>, e.g. "<+05>" (quoted form - not supported by QNX?)
        // offset   :=  [+|-]hh[:mm[:ss]]
        // rule     :=  Mm.n.d[/time], e.g. "M3.1.0/2"
        // m        :=  1..12
        // n        :=  1..5
        // d        :=  0..6, or 1..31
        // time     :=  hh[:mm[:ss]], leading + or - not allowed
        // 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="posixTz"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool IsValidPosixTZString(string posixTz)
        {
            try {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(posixTz)) {
                    return false;
                }
                string[] parts = posixTz.Split(',');
                if (parts.Length > 3) {
                    return false;
                }

                // may be in quoted form from POSIX.1-2001, e.g. "<+09>",
                // or standard and daylight saving time (DST) zone abbreviations
                string zones = parts[0];
                int nextIndex;
                string stdAbbreviation;
                TimeSpan stdOffset;
                if (!ParseZone(zones, 0, out nextIndex, out stdAbbreviation, out stdOffset)) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (stdOffset == TimeSpan.MaxValue) {
                    // std must have an offset
                    return false;
                }
                bool hasDst = false;
                if (nextIndex != -1 && nextIndex < zones.Length) {
                    string dstAbbreviation;
                    TimeSpan dstOffset;
                    if (!ParseZone(zones, nextIndex, out nextIndex, out dstAbbreviation, out dstOffset)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (dstOffset == TimeSpan.MaxValue) {
                        // dst may not have an offset, assume 0h00
                        dstOffset = TimeSpan.Zero;
                    }
                    hasDst = true;
                }
                if (nextIndex != zones.Length) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (parts.Length == 1) {
                    return true;
                }
                if (!hasDst) {
                    // cannot have rule info unless dst is present
                    return false;
                }
                if (parts.Length > 1) {
                    if (!GetRule(parts[1], out TimeZoneInfo.TransitionTime t)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                if (parts.Length > 2) {
                    if (!GetRule(parts[2], out TimeZoneInfo.TransitionTime t)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                // invalid, just return false
            }
            return false;
        }

        // Process a zone "name [offset]", e.g. "MST7" or "PST-1:45", or "<+01>1"
        private static bool ParseZone(string zone, int startIndex, out int nextIndex, out string abbreviation, out TimeSpan offset)
        {
            nextIndex = -1;
            abbreviation = string.Empty;
            offset = TimeSpan.MaxValue;     // offset is MaxValue if no offset is defined

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(zone) || (uint)startIndex >= zone.Length) {
                return false;
            }

            // the Posix specs. which state that the abbreviation must be alpha characters only
            // or quoted form <...>, we validate it this way
            // (according to QNX documentation "Any characters except for a leading colon (:), 
            // digits, comma (,), minus (-), plus (+), and ASCII NUL (\0) are allowed"
            // we do it the Posix way)

            // abbreviation
            int ix;
            if (zone[startIndex] == '<') {
                // quoted format, e.g. "<-04>4<-03>", syntax is "<...>n[<...>[n]]"
                ix = zone.IndexOf('>', startIndex);
                if (ix <= 0) {
                    return false;
                }
                // allows alphanumeric and + - characters between <...>
                for (int n = startIndex + 1; n < ix; ++n) {
                    char ch = zone[n];
                    if (!char.IsLetterOrDigit(ch) && ch != '+' && ch != '-') {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                // skip trailing '>'
                ++ix;
            }
            else {
                // unquoted format, find end of zone abbreviation, e.g. "MST7MDT" is "MST7"
                ix = startIndex;
                while (ix < zone.Length && char.IsLetter(zone[ix])) {
                    ++ix;
                }
                // allows only alphabetic characters, but we just skipped those
            }
            abbreviation = zone.Substring(startIndex, ix - startIndex);
            if (abbreviation.Length < 3) {
                return false;
            }

            // offset
            if (ix == zone.Length) {
                nextIndex = ix;
                return true;            // no offset
            }
            // find end of offset
            startIndex = ix;
            while (ix < zone.Length && "+-0123456789:".IndexOf(zone[ix]) >= 0) {
                ++ix;
            }
            nextIndex = ix;
            string soffset = zone.Substring(startIndex, ix - startIndex);
            return GetTime(soffset, out offset);
        }

        // Process a rule, e.g. "Mm.w.d", "Jn" or "n" with optional "/time", e.g. "M10.5.0/1:45"
        private static bool GetRule(string srule, out TimeZoneInfo.TransitionTime transitionTime)
        {
            transitionTime = new TimeZoneInfo.TransitionTime();

            try {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(srule)) {
                    return false;
                }
                string[] parts = srule.Split('/');
                if (parts.Length > 2) {
                    return false;
                }

                // get the transition time, defaults to 2am if time not specified
                // must be 0..24h (the old format with range of -167..+167 is not supported)
                DateTime time = DefaultTransitionTime;
                if (parts.Length == 2) {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parts[1]) || !char.IsDigit(parts[1][0])) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (!GetTime(parts[1], out TimeSpan timeSpan)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (timeSpan == Hours24) {
                        // note! CreateXXXDateRule() does not support time >= 24 hours
                        timeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 23, 59, 59, 999);
                    }
                    time = new DateTime(1, 1, 1) + timeSpan;
                }

                // "Mm.w.d"
                if (parts[0].StartsWith("M", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
                    string[] ruleParts = parts[0].Substring(1).Split('.');
                    if (ruleParts.Length != 3) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    int month = int.Parse(ruleParts[0]);
                    int week = int.Parse(ruleParts[1]);
                    int day = int.Parse(ruleParts[2]);

                    if (month < 1 || month > 12 || week < 1 || week > 5 || day < 0 || day > 6) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    // assume this throws an exception if something is wrong
                    transitionTime = TimeZoneInfo.TransitionTime.CreateFloatingDateRule(time, month, week, (DayOfWeek)day);
                }

                // "Jn" day of year, ignoring leap years
                else if (parts[0].StartsWith("J", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
                    int dayOfYear = int.Parse(parts[0].Substring(1));
                    // if leap year and day is after 29th Feb, subtract one day
                    if (DateTime.IsLeapYear(DateTime.Now.Year)) {
                        DateTime feb29 = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 2, 29);
                        if (dayOfYear > feb29.DayOfYear) {
                            --dayOfYear;
                        }
                    }
                    DateTime date = DateTime.MinValue.AddDays(dayOfYear);
                    transitionTime = TimeZoneInfo.TransitionTime.CreateFixedDateRule(time, date.Month, date.Day);
                }

                // "n" day of year with leap year
                else {
                    int dayOfYear = int.Parse(parts[0]);
                    DateTime date = DateTime.MinValue.AddDays(dayOfYear);
                    transitionTime = TimeZoneInfo.TransitionTime.CreateFixedDateRule(time, date.Month, date.Day);
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                // happens if int.Parse() or CreateXXXDateRule() fails, we just return false
            }
            return false;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Convert a time string "[+|-]hh[:mm[:ss[.ms]]]" to a TimeSpan.
        /// A number can have one or more digits, the number of digits is not checked.
        /// Spec says "You can use one or more digits; the value is always interpreted as a decimal number."
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="stime">String to convert</param>
        /// <param name="timeSpan">TimeSpan</param>
        /// <returns>true if valid, false if invalid</returns>
        private static bool GetTime(string stime, out TimeSpan timeSpan)
        {
            timeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stime)) {
                return false;
            }
            try {
                // remove leading sign
                bool negative = stime.StartsWith("-");
                if (negative || stime.StartsWith("+")) {
                    stime = stime.Substring(1);
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stime)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                // hh[:mm[:ss[.ms]]]
                int hh = 0, mm = 0, ss = 0, ms = 0;

                /*ms are not used in posix time zones but are needed for IANA database times, so leave this here
                // get milliseconds, if present
                string[] s = stime.Split('.');
                if (s.Length > 2) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (s.Length > 1) {
                    // fractional seconds, in milliseconds
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s[1])) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    string sms = (s[1] + "000").Substring(0, 3);
                    ms = int.Parse(sms);
                }
                s = s[0].Split(':');
                */
                string[] s = stime.Split(':');
                if (s.Length > 3) {
                    return false;
                }
                hh = int.Parse(s[0]);       // hours must be present

                if (s.Length > 1) {
                    mm = int.Parse(s[1]);
                }
                if (s.Length > 2) {
                    ss = int.Parse(s[2]);
                }
                timeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, hh, mm, ss, ms);

                //>>> this check is needed only for posix time zones, not for IANA database times
                // max. is 24 hours
                if (hh > 24 || mm > 59 || ss > 59 || timeSpan > Hours24) {
                    return false;
                }
                //<<<

                if (negative) {
                    timeSpan = timeSpan.Negate();
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                // happens if int.Parse() or new TimeSpan() fails, just return false
            }
            return false;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the number of days in the given year and month, taking leap years into account. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="year">e.g. 2019</param>
        /// <param name="month">1..12</param>
        /// <returns>28..31, or -1 if month or year is invalid</returns>
        private static int GetDaysInMonth(int year, int month)
        {
            if (month < 1 || month > 12 || year < 0) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (month == 2 && DateTime.IsLeapYear(year)) {
                return 29;
            }
            return daysInMonth[month - 1];
        }
        private static readonly int[] daysInMonth = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };


    }
}
```

Comment: Answering questions here is appreciated but they should give enough details so that if the offsite page disappears then the answer here still has value. In this case there is no code here to show how to get the wanted information. Please see the [help] pages and in particular *"Provide context for links"* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: By the way, the same comment applies to the other answer dated 2018-12.

Comment: Hi AdrianHHH, Yes, my link may well disappear in a few years. I could add the whole file, but being a small-time user, I'm not sure how to do it.