# Convert windows timezone info to OpenWRT format

Tags: c#, windows, timezone, openwrt

I find myself in the unfortunate position of having to set a timer on an embedded device which expects the timezone passed along with the start and end time.  The correct timezone for my location is CST6CDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0
However I am not the only user of my software.  I have people using it in many countries and the product i'm manipulating is from Sweden.  Is there an easy way to convert the timezones, either through a library or other, or do I need to manually create a lookup table?

Comment: Given your example, i assume with "OpenWRT format" you mean POSIX time-zone strings. If so, a cursory search here on Stackoverflow leads me to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53870236/convert-net-timezoneinfo-to-posix-time-zone

Comment: As of Net 6 the Framework TimeZoneInfo class should be able to handle those timezones. But i assume you are not on Net 6 or above?

Comment: @Ralf - TimeZoneInfo will work with IANA time zones, but not POSIX time zones.

Answer (score 0):

From reading [the OpenWRT docs](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/system_configuration), it would appear that OpenWRT is prepared for working with two different types of time zones:

- On Systems with IANA time zone support (i.e., a Linux `tzdata` package or other similar support), the `zonename` system option can be set to the IANA time zone identifier, such as `"America/Chicago"`.
- On Systems without IANA support, the `timezone` system option can be set to a POSIX time zone string, such as `"CST6CDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0"`.

Ideally, you should use IANA identifiers if the system you are targeting supports them.  Reasons are described in the section titled "POSIX style time zones" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

- If the host system is running .NET on Linux or iOS, the `TimeZoneInfo` class will already be working with IANA time zones.  Just use the `.Id` property, such as `TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id`.
- If the host system is running on Windows and using .NET 6 or greater, you can get the same effect using the new [Time Zone Conversion APIs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/date-time-and-time-zone-enhancements-in-net-6/#time-zone-conversion-apis), such as `TimeZoneInfo.TryConvertWindowsIdToIanaId`.  However, this works only on systems where ICU data is present.
- If you may be running on a variety of systems, or have older host systems in use, then use my [TimeZoneConverter library](https://github.com/mattjohnsonpint/TimeZoneConverter) instead.

Pass the IANA time zone identifier to the OpenWRT `zonename` on the device.

Additionally, if your devices are systems where IANA tzdata is not present and you must rely on POSIX time zones, then you can use my [`TimeZoneConverter.Posix` library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TimeZoneConverter.Posix/) on a host system to generate an appropriate POSIX time zone string to pass into the OpenWRT `timezone` option.

Example:

```
string posix = PosixTimeZone.FromWindowsTimeZoneId("Central Standard Time");
// Result: "CST6CDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0"
```

Keep in mind that POSIX strings should be re-generated periodically because they only contain *current year* information.  If a change happens to a particular time zone mid year, then you will need a new POSIX string.  For that reason, you also can't reliably work with historical time on the device itself.  A good plan is to have some normal process where your device calls home for updates, and include the time zone string as part of those updates.

Comment: thank you I will try your examples tuesday.  Historical data isn't necessary to support since i'm merely setting a current on/off schedule.  For reasons beyond my understanding, the routine won't work without passing timezone information even though the data is passed in three values:  seconds since midnight, seconds from midnight to turn on, seconds from midnight to turn off.  You would think that would be enough.  Without passing a timezone, it simply doesn't turn on at the correct hour.

Comment: Most systems have an internal clock that is set to UTC, preferably synchronized with NTP.  The time zone is then required to compute the local time.  Otherwise "midnight" is meaningless.

Comment: I'll agree with that except that i just told you at 1am that it's been 3600 seconds since midnight.   I'm going to try passing "America/Chicago" and see if it accepts it.  If so, that will solve my problem completely.  Note the host system is absolutely not running .net on it.  It's an esp32 controller.